# Angular Material Side Navigation bar

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

In my angular 6 project I am having angular sidebar navigation, It's working fine in desktop view. but I need same side bar to work for mobile view as overlay mode.

How to achieve it,

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/angular/vqngodbvbkr?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using angular-material there is ng generate @angular/material:material-nav feature.

generate navbar component

```
 ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name <component-name>
```

example:

```
 ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name navbar
```

here is blog where you can read about it.

https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4